# Checking equality of vector elements

Tags: matlab, vector, equality

Say we have the following vectors in `matlab`:

```
v1=[2 2 2 2 2 2 2]

v2=[2 2 2 2 3 2 2]
```

How can we check that all the elements in each vector are equal or not?

**EDIT (NOTE)**

I'm **not** asking about comparing the two vectors to each other, but the elements inside each vector together. For example, `v1` has all its elements equal to each other, while `v2` not.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html

Comment: @j.holetzeck. Please see my post edit. I'm **not** trying to compare the two vectors together, but the elements of the vector to each other. Thanks

Comment: have you considered the case where all elements are NaN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
length(unique(v1)) == 1

>> 1

length(unique(v2)) == 1

>> 0
```

To exclude a number that I don't want to include here, e.g 0 in this example:

```
v3=[2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0]
length(unique(v3(v3 ~= 0))) == 1
>> 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I want to use the command you suggested, is there a way to include a number that I don't want to include here? Say that for instance I don`t want `0` to be included here, what can I do?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt `unique` is a little overkill here, no? :)

Comment: @EitanT yeah probably not the best optimization :-) But I guess the OP won't apply it on huge vectors anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if all the elements in the vector are the same by doing

```
>> all(v1 == v1(1))

ans =

     1

>> all(v2 == v2(1))

ans =

     0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I want to use the command you suggested, is there a way to include a number that I don't want to include here? Say that for instance I don`t want `0` to be included here, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare element-wise like this:

```
v1 == v2
```

which returns

```
[ 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ]
```

Then use the `all` function to return `true` if all elements are true:

```
all(v1 == v2)
```

Comment: It is not about comparing the two vectors. I meant comparing the elements of each vector together. Thanks

Comment: I guess that's why it's better to always show the desired output in the questions.